# Why coudn't I use function grantpt in Linux?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I want to use function grantpt in my program. I include its header file `<stdlib.h>`, but the compiler still give me the `warning: implicit declaration of grantpt`, which means it cound't find the declaration in `stdlib.h`. I `grep` the header file and find the declaration:

```
stdlib.h:920:extern int grantpt (int __fd) __THROW;
```

And my glibc version is 2.17, the official manual says this function is included since version 2.1.

Here is my test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned long u_l;  

int main(){
    int errno = grantpt(1);
    printf("errno = %d\n", errno);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you read [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/grantpt.3.html) you will see that you need the macro `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to be defined, and it's apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include<sys/poll.h>

typedef unsigned long u_l;

int main()
{
    int errno = grantpt(1);

    printf("errno = %d\n", errno);

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles without that warning

See [Man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/grantpt.html) clearly says that you need to define  `_XOPEN_SOURCE` before including `stdlib.h` for accessing `grantpt()`

Comment: Now it goes well! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you in stackoverflow is accepting answer and upvote them

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04: #define _GNU_SOURCE instead of _XOPEN_SOURCE worked for me

Comment: That is not how you retrieve the *`errno`*, granpt(3) signals returning `-1` that it set it not return what was it.